# Flatten a nested array but also append information from another array in python

Tags: python

Hi I'm currently doing machine learning ,here is something complex to me . Here is a dictionary , which contain 'data' and 'name' array , the number of subarray are the same , which means , they are linked to each other by the same level and position of array . for example , data `[-12.746249259898983, -40.618078412505398, -53.765980530841738, 5.2261728305123398, 0.12162578441442624, -5.7948531230422988, -449155.5052490317, 0.91963697398417421]'s total name is 100, and data -12.746249259898983 which inside that array 's name is '100.0'.` However ,some name can represent a single level array or nested array .

```
{'data': [[ [-12.746249259898983, -40.618078412505398, -53.765980530841738, 5.2261728305123398, 0.12162578441442624, -5.7948531230422988, -449155.5052490317, 0.91963697398417421], [-98.037517854387147, -221.057540054155, -159.4518899022695, 2.8761226353857214, -5.3555144738112865, -8.4617336886131636, -1078807.4268864163, -13.13441127151575], [20.903581634463947, 25.329222910065528, 5.412150882014295, 9.8334972052776468, 5.0344964646349721, -4.9321628192214595, 465839.20729012048, 13.101100255062818], [6906900.092440652, 41574768.75710336, 10927415.550909607, 11310.66577299293, 8798.704300502737, 8799.682832152064, 183845205120901.88, 112667.8001209582], [23668.070022021395, 50044.215525581945, 31776.017910004855, 1187.8286828919734, 1004.3222306303834, 1097.6394464618995, 144191707.36233276, 3204.3354707366584]], [[-12.746249259898983, -40.618078412505398, -53.765980530841738, 5.2261728305123398, 0.12162578441442624, -5.7948531230422988, -449155.5052490317, 0.91963697398417421], [-98.037517854387147, -221.057540054155, -159.4518899022695, 2.8761226353857214, -5.3555144738112865, -8.4617336886131636, -1078807.4268864163, -13.13441127151575], [20.903581634463947, 25.329222910065528, 5.412150882014295, 9.8334972052776468, 5.0344964646349721, -4.9321628192214595, 465839.20729012048, 13.101100255062818], [6906900.092440652, 41574768.75710336, 10927415.550909607, 11310.66577299293, 8798.704300502737, 8799.682832152064, 183845205120901.88, 112667.8001209582], [23668.070022021395, 50044.215525581945, 31776.017910004855, 1187.8286828919734, 1004.3222306303834, 1097.6394464618995, 144191707.36233276, 3204.3354707366584]], [[105488.30345760827], [3289.7903599842557], [1084894.676814588], [14144.972809638024], [-0.28007907692942713, 0.22442925752465423, 0.53764244860950272], [-0.17191558990475442, -0.79049974125170352, 0.50351854155808451], [0.82458612961411526, 0.76972732632638607, 0.85167351947413183], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], [[523.30228588437444, 45.819830845333598, 28.816263055785519, -13.399823220658771, -4.3270838526008539, 6.3733684200628371, 8595795.3597348519, 8.384858849273007], [475.31250457055427, -228.32291772427124, -176.40773800372068, -18.093080976490384, -10.369967809128632, 4.2210565912106244, 7098802.0557304611, -7.1771997695309269], [588.25628456928746, 294.97718389914189, 262.91102656456047, -10.427939493412241, 1.4416568032097778, 8.5693307123828362, 10382020.11504475, 25.39147629554094], [48743197.97266989, 30241091.100284778, 18077525.93554477, 34815.577041886056, 13488.38255077284, 9285.35861896049, 1.33034499502354e+16, 137928.77372005512], [88438.08631445921, 56149.17419161105, 43172.45645293931, 2264.570124291333, 1314.3600405678308, 1119.5488398712207, 1452689415.79519, 3947.582767320521]], [[523.30228588437444, 45.819830845333598, 28.816263055785519, -13.399823220658771, -4.3270838526008539, 6.3733684200628371, 8595795.3597348519, 8.384858849273007], [475.31250457055427, -228.32291772427124, -176.40773800372068, -18.093080976490384, -10.369967809128632, 4.2210565912106244, 7098802.0557304611, -7.1771997695309269], [588.25628456928746, 294.97718389914189, 262.91102656456047, -10.427939493412241, 1.4416568032097778, 8.5693307123828362, 10382020.11504475, 25.39147629554094], [48743197.97266989, 30241091.100284778, 18077525.93554477, 34815.577041886056, 13488.38255077284, 9285.35861896049, 1.33034499502354e+16, 137928.77372005512], [88438.08631445921, 56149.17419161105, 43172.45645293931, 2264.570124291333, 1314.3600405678308, 1119.5488398712207, 1452689415.79519, 3947.582767320521]], [[187759.71695900976], [4698.479004730381], [1027854.7076158928], [23680.601277936279], [-0.15439507445075032, -0.075920544072209092, 0.66503179584326411], [0.46923791478750121, -0.69581655384848085, -0.72748336248359702], [0.21092970277607359, 0.14987815855097059, 0.81570800991816339], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], [[13.396472405737706, -18.359344127602043, 36.826432688017405, -5.4414333610698273, -10.694878175101108, 7.9448139442889429, 10816437.307411144, 0.19533722684887966], [-15.189934136155252, -200.13563785186551, -109.36104765476506, -11.7199280963678, -17.858474582674631, 6.8660269597012578, 1044415.9081568928, -1.3455015074983672], [72.972793023164726, 181.79005098185144, 199.11746464797852, -4.9326473220315465, -5.0927085243861612, 14.603766227834551, 19440694.34613679, 1.7339256547371409], [1384309.4521168934, 8347935.341004645, 7917333.307240587, 29378.49283018787, 32011.489849631027, 36975.920226450995, 3.3465760911327116e+16, 911.4959262418305], [11296.673361701862, 32414.28539427253, 29892.827418169887, 1857.859505569651, 2026.9222424051377, 2193.920509546758, 1961706423.8618736, 309.5250420877879]], [[13.396472405737706, -18.359344127602043, 36.826432688017405, -5.4414333610698273, -10.694878175101108, 7.9448139442889429, 10816437.307411144, 0.19533722684887966], [-15.189934136155252, -200.13563785186551, -109.36104765476506, -11.7199280963678, -17.858474582674631, 6.8660269597012578, 1044415.9081568928, -1.3455015074983672], [72.972793023164726, 181.79005098185144, 199.11746464797852, -4.9326473220315465, -5.0927085243861612, 14.603766227834551, 19440694.34613679, 1.7339256547371409], [1384309.4521168934, 8347935.341004645, 7917333.307240587, 29378.49283018787, 32011.489849631027, 36975.920226450995, 3.3465760911327116e+16, 911.4959262418305], [11296.673361701862, 32414.28539427253, 29892.827418169887, 1857.859505569651, 2026.9222424051377, 2193.920509546758, 1961706423.8618736, 309.5250420877879]], [[73603.78617414428], [6078.7022575215515], [625733.61247557076], [45672.991571875093], [0.043448760802826739, 0.23278517949941815, -0.4412484230587122], [0.73571039835259899, -0.97150579562327632, -0.85102560336644162], [0.43273760788012128, 0.59834831245116515, 0.76048753082083709], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], [[-4312.4566991228266, 111.37588860973005, -369.27441630396561, 1.0221741887428542, 10.264001072191407, -0.64794873494824146, -26535.315429097467, 3733.3894352435532], [-4391.6993203248185, 2.1930377207860374, -556.18155858830767, -2.8465168776531042, 6.8275893393989735, -2.992456229023948, -134301.2497497506, 3085.6901898537008], [-4265.6954381966243, 490.57527638444799, -106.53884094262287, 2.6903234802233951, 14.899879413776139, 1.2542987455939745, 124282.28583445404, 4312.3584935051322], [3154842424.3400664, 66787778.51899314, 37678234.97132428, 1886.122427403741, 27432.6986991385, 1552.4163983149103, 9721961586366.314, 2438338620.274526], [728805.1821517571, 88155.59598567848, 68098.54374026474, 500.1103528606394, 1980.9257474491533, 442.23338752473614, 30550976.541662402, 630942.8145561604]], [[-4312.4566991228266, 111.37588860973005, -369.27441630396561, 1.0221741887428542, 10.264001072191407, -0.64794873494824146, -26535.315429097467, 3733.3894352435532], [-4391.6993203248185, 2.1930377207860374, -556.18155858830767, -2.8465168776531042, 6.8275893393989735, -2.992456229023948, -134301.2497497506, 3085.6901898537008], [-4265.6954381966243, 490.57527638444799, -106.53884094262287, 2.6903234802233951, 14.899879413776139, 1.2542987455939745, 124282.28583445404, 4312.3584935051322], [3154842424.3400664, 66787778.51899314, 37678234.97132428, 1886.122427403741, 27432.6986991385, 1552.4163983149103, 9721961586366.314, 2438338620.274526], [728805.1821517571, 88155.59598567848, 68098.54374026474, 500.1103528606394, 1980.9257474491533, 442.23338752473614, 30550976.541662402, 630942.8145561604]], [[885059.3218777011], [2923.2694878345296], [2236604.1192022543], [8808.54792655048], [-0.67448622916323409, -0.50158101433414648, 0.59882229555795874], [-0.78104865531713752, -0.76429278912704701, 0.63516453144318363], [0.20462205303333128, 0.84578383059323625, 0.59233056719450861], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], [[-259.72665899990471, -83.479321394167755, -121.15460261636761, -9.5566399167895906, -10.751374026150252, 6.9216241967193373, 14885579.317280933, -21.445028515600601], [-443.23038559240399, -180.2214836399863, -177.88859043152414, -17.157662401019614, -16.084610849457864, 2.4976391930266151, 10238968.298370993, -44.428320700622876], [-303.57098842656001, 48.893029546726382, -69.225922326687694, -3.4513266189454357, -7.9243380822281777, 11.288531677853044, 19912765.253164865, 2.6916854500962191], [41735450.1518125, 24390799.584619, 9017310.78529916, 28630.03604412623, 27367.43896473854, 17107.884579392492, 4.242364584898001e+16, 253955.56763607], [75924.07800808054, 43290.42097424058, 29303.03439665969, 1778.5410136020398, 1988.7244606604343, 1372.5600617945775, 2515662904.620479, 4776.4285037481795]], [[-259.72665899990471, -83.479321394167755, -121.15460261636761, -9.5566399167895906, -10.751374026150252, 6.9216241967193373, 14885579.317280933, -21.445028515600601], [-443.23038559240399, -180.2214836399863, -177.88859043152414, -17.157662401019614, -16.084610849457864, 2.4976391930266151, 10238968.298370993, -44.428320700622876], [-303.57098842656001, 48.893029546726382, -69.225922326687694, -3.4513266189454357, -7.9243380822281777, 11.288531677853044, 19912765.253164865, 2.6916854500962191], [41735450.1518125, 24390799.584619, 9017310.78529916, 28630.03604412623, 27367.43896473854, 17107.884579392492, 4.242364584898001e+16, 253955.56763607], [75924.07800808054, 43290.42097424058, 29303.03439665969, 1778.5410136020398, 1988.7244606604343, 1372.5600617945775, 2515662904.620479, 4776.4285037481795]], [[148517.53337898097], [5139.82553605705], [1242960.9144121602], [27678.070645658128], [-0.072211399963483205, -0.01330100771527422, 0.50872724028242133], [0.12899184324668519, -0.83705081189441499, -0.30244329509440016], [0.8127044117719453, 0.76986342841470423, 0.67385354549078191], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]],
 'name': [[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105], [106, 107, 108], [109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116], [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205], [206, 207, 208], [209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216], [300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305], [306, 307, 308], [309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316], [400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405], [406, 407, 408], [409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416], [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505], [506, 507, 508], [509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516]]}
```

Now I want to flatten the data and make all of them to ground floor ,however ,once I did that ,there name will mismatch.

More generally(remind that data it self might get more nested level, but address won't) ,if I got:
`{'data':[[[1],[2,3,[4]]],[[5,6],[7,8,9]]],'name':[[100,101],[202,203]]}` which `100 is the name of [1] , 101 is the name of [2,3,[4]],202 is name of [5,6],203 is the name of [7,8,9]`

more clearly :

```
`{'data':[[ [1],[2,3,[4]] ],[ [5,6],[7,8,9]]]
             |      |           |      |
'name':  [[ 100,   101    ],[  202,   203  ]]
```

, once I flatten data and become :`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` the corresponding name array is still [100,101,202,203] which means mismatched, I want them matched , so when I flatten a nested array ,I could get the same name of the elements inside , like get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and `[100.0,101.0,101.1,101.2,101.2,202.0,202.1,203.0,203.1,203.2]` since `[2,3,[4]]` are all named `101`,100.0 means the first element in the array which is 2,101.2 means the third one in the array,(don't care about further nested representation [4] is still 101.2 but not 101.20, and [[4]] is also 101.2 but not 101.200,of cause , if you are kind of magician ,I wish I could have this cool name style, but I think it's complex enough for a question)  ,thus ,the name array also get correct flatten.

It's kind of brainstorm.. Thanks for any help..

### I have rewrite the question , last day I found some bugs in my original data with the help of @schlezzz15 , really thanks , shamly the data is too big and hard to find bug inside ,really sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem.

A solution with [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and compiler.ast.flatten

```
from compiler.ast import flatten
from itertools import chain,cycle
d = {'data':[[ [1],[2,3,[4]] ],[ [5,6],[7,8,9]]],       
     'name':  [[ 100,   101    ],[  202,   203  ]]}

data,name = chain(*d["data"]),list(chain(*d["name"]))
data = [flatten(sublist)for sublist in data ]

print name
# >>> [100, 101, 202, 203]
print data
# >>> [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

aligned = zip(name,data)
print aligned
# >>> [(100, [1]), (101, [2, 3, 4]), (202, [5, 6]), (203, [7, 8, 9])]

result = [zip(cycle([n]),da) for n,da in aligned]
print result
# >>> [[(100, 1)], [(101, 2), (101, 3), (101, 4)], [(202, 5), (202, 6)], [(203, 7), (203, 8), (203, 9)]]

flattened_result = list(chain(*result))
print flattened_result
# >>> [(100, 1), (101, 2), (101, 3), (101, 4), (202, 5), (202, 6), (203, 7), (203, 8), (203, 9)]


string_result = [str(item[0])+"."+str(item[1]-1) for item in flattened_result]
print string_result
# >>> ['100.0', '101.1', '101.2', '101.3', '202.4', '202.5', '203.6', '203.7', '203.8']


# I do not recommend the below version, only on OP's request.
d = {'data':[[ [1],[2,3,[4]] ],[ [5,6],[7,8,9]]],       
     'name':  [[ 100,   101    ],[  202,   203  ]]}
all_in_one =[str(item[0])+"."+str(item[1]-1) for item in chain(*[zip(cycle([n]),da) for n,da in zip((chain(*d["name"])),(flatten(sublist)for sublist in chain(*d["data"])))])]
print all_in_one == string_result
# >>> True
```

I'm not sure which kind of output format you would like, so I included all of the intermediary results. It should be easy for you to get the one you want. If you specify a desired output, I will amend my solution.

Comment: Thanks!The code you written looks very 'pythonic' ,I'm currently on the train unable to test your code but soon will ,could you flatten both data and name into ground floor in one goal?For example the first print(one above aligned print),the data will flatten to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and name will correspondingly change to [100.0,101.0,101.1,101.2,202.0,202.1,203.0,203.1,203.2]? I could do it separately but I think you could offer more pythonic way to do that and I'm curious to see how to do that :) thanks!

Comment: If you are asking whether I could do this in one line, the answer is yes, I could. However it doesn't mean that it would be more "pythonic". I would consider it a huge mess. Do you want the result as [str(name.index)]?

Comment: still want to see it !yes !

Answer (score 0):

This could work. I haven't tested it.

```
from compiler.ast import flatten

def main():
    dict_ = {'data': [1, [2, 3, [4]]], 'name': [1000, 1001]}
    data = dict_.get('data')
    name = dict_.get('name')
    flatten_dict = {}

    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        if isinstance(data[i], int):
            flatten_dict.update({data[i]: name[i]})
        elif isinstance(data[i], list):
            list_flatten = flatten(data[i])
            for item in list_flatten:
                flatten_dict.update({item: name[i]})

    print flatten_dict

main()
```

Comment: I have tested with original data I got , elements are all return like this :11.73431016192542: [1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1070, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087] which is hard to tell , I think the only way to do it is by using recursion ..

Comment: Oh I supposed the number array was just a list not a list of lists (etc). This code won't work. My fault.